# What are the differences between the iOS and PC/Console versions of XCOM, if any?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, ios

XCOM: Enemy Unknown is available for the iPad/iPhone now, but the only information I've been able to find on the differences between this port and the PC/console version is:

- Some maps were removed.
- The graphical detail has been scaled back to roughly PlayStation 2-era levels.

I'd love to know more details. How many maps are missing? (Which ones?) Is the content from the DLC available? Most importantly, are there any gameplay differences?

Comment: `The graphical detail has been scaled back to roughly PlayStation 2-era levels.` Well, you can't expect a mobile game to look the same as (or better than) a game for stationary devices. Also note, that the controls will be different too unless you use a gamepad (not sure if gamepad is supported, though)

Comment: @Nolonar: I'm not saying there's anything *wrong* with that, I just included it for the sake of completeness. I'd probably play the hell out of this game even if it had NES-era graphics. :)

Comment: I'd love to check out this game with NES graphics :D

Comment: @nolonar just go play x-com:EU :P. I still think its the best xcom game

Comment: @spartacus You had me confused here. I totally forgot that the original is called X-COM (aka. UFO), whereas the current iteration is called XCOM (without hyphen). But good call, I'll see if I can get my hands on that piece of classic ;)

Comment: It's [on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/7760/) these days, along with the sequel, [Terror from the Deep](http://store.steampowered.com/app/7650/). If you do want to play it, the best way is to take the files (from Steam or from a boxed version) and drop them into the [OpenXCom](http://openxcom.org/) engine; it runs much better and fixes a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 9):

As you have already found, one of the main differences is the drop in graphics quality. This means, according to [Pocket Gamer](http://www.pocketgamer.co.uk/r/iPhone/XCOM%3A+Enemy+Unknown/feature.asp?c=51715):

- Lower resolution
- No mouth animations
- Fewer dynamic camera angles (kill cams, presumably)
- Lower quality lighting

Additionally, the PvP multiplayer mode is not available. However, according to both [Venture Beat](http://venturebeat.com/2013/06/17/2k-games-wants-20-for-xcom-enemy-unknown-on-ios/) and [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2013/05/30/xcom-ios-multiplayer-to-be-added-after-launch/), it will be added at a later date.

There's an [interview](http://www.gamereactor.eu/articles/73141/Xcom%3A+Enemy+Unknown+iOS+Interview/) with Jake Solomon, the lead designer, stating

> "The amazing thing is that all of the gameplay is there, and we just
>   had to trim a few maps in order to get it to work on mobile."

and

> "The interface has been changed slightly, taking the PC interface as
>   the starting point.

As for the DLC, in Joystiq's [announcement article](http://www.joystiq.com/2013/03/23/xcom-enemy-unknown-iOS/) they say that the Elite Soldier DLC **is** included but that the Slingshot DLC **is not**. <strike>As far as I can see, the Second Wave patch is similarly not included.</strike>

**Edit:** A recent patch has added the Second Wave options to the iOS version (thanks to bpcookson for the heads up).

Comment: So what are the missing maps?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any listing of the missing maps and I don't own the game. Hopefully someone can add the info to my answer.

Comment: I just beat the game on Normal and unlocked Second Wave options.  Playing on an iPhone.